# Wireless Using Intel Wireless 7260 Won't Activate (eOS Loki)

Tags: release-loki, wifi, intel

Whenever I attempt to activate my wireless setting, it immediately turns off. I have no problem using wired. I am using an Intel 7260 dual-band, and the Bluetooth works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a laptop? Brand?

With my HP Omen and Intel 7260 (no dual-band) I had to blacklist acer_wmi to connect with Wifi.

Create a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/ with

> blacklist acer_wmi

Save and Reboot.

Comment: Using an HP SplitX2 laptop, and that worked perfectly. Thanks!